# How can I get the syntax ID of a named group?

Tags: vimscript

`synID()` lets you get the syntax ID associated with a particular character at a particular line and column. This syntax ID is useful for querying other aspects of the syntax highlighting group (such as the name, colors, et cetera).

I've [written a plugin](https://github.com/jpetrie/vim-mixology) that uses `synID` to let you interactively tweak the color of specific groups. I would like to [support editing groups that don't ever appear in the document text](https://github.com/jpetrie/vim-mixology/issues/2) (the cursor can never be over those, generally). The most reasonable way to do this would require me to look up a syntax ID based on the group's name.

Is there a built-in function to look up this mapping? Or do I need to build a look-up table myself?

Comment: Interesting plugin; I hope you are aware of [the ColorSel plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=927), which also implements a (generic) color selector.

Comment: Not seen that one, but I know there's quite a few. Thanks for pointing it out. Mostly I write these for my own edification, I find that they teach me interesting things about vim.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for `hlID()`, and the odd `hl`-prefix probably made you not find it.

#### Example

```
:echo hlID("Comment")
46
```

Comment: *Right* after I committed a solution using a gross loop to scan manually. :D Thanks!

Comment: Saved me from having to write that loop though, thank you!